# Echo through loop of ACF Select under user content

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, select, advanced-custom-fields

So I have made a select dropdown in ACF with the name of highest_professional_certification [Screenshot 1]. I have a user dashboard where people fill in some data, I have it working with a single input but I'm struggling with getting the select box to show.

[image]

I currently have

```
$user_highest_professional_certification = get_the_author_meta('highest_professional_certification', $user_id);

<div class="col-sm-3">
   <label for="highest_professional_certification"><?php echo esc_html__('Highest Professional Certification', 'listingpro'); ?></label>
   <select type="text" class="form-control" name="highest_professional_certification" id="highest_professional_certification" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Select Highest Professional Certification','listingpro'); ?>" >

    */Need to loop through values here */

   </select>
</div>


/* Input working */

<div class="col-sm-3">
   <label for="current_living_country"><?php echo esc_html__('Current Living Country', 'listingpro'); ?</label>
   <input value="<?php echo esc_attr($current_living_country); ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="current_living_country" id="current_living_country" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Enter Current Living Country','listingpro'); ?>" />
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? You say you're struggling to get the select box to show, but its not clear where this should appear - in the user info in the admin or somewhere on the frontend? Can you also show us the code you have where it works with a single input? This might help us understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I basically want to loop through the select options from that ACF field rather than hardcoding them

Comment: Ok, but I don't see any code that works with the ACF fields you created - neither the one that works or the one that doesn't. You say the second input works - where are you getting the value for `$current_living_country`?